# Create custom DLL plugins for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-standard, class-library

I'm creating a custom DLL file for my Unity workflow by create .Net solution in Rider. But I have 2 issues:

1. I want to save all my animation function which I created and used before. All my animation function use Leantween. When import Leantween.dll into solution and build, everything right. But when using in Unity, i got this error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'LeanTween, Version=1.0.6223.20226, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

2. I also want to save my resuseable function like this:

> 

```
    public static void SetAlphaImage(Image image, float amount)
    {
        var tmp = image.color;
        tmp.a = amount;
        image.color = tmp;
    }
```

I imported UnityEngine.UI.dll then build but i got this error:

> Utilities.cs(39, 29): [CS0012] The type 'Color' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Im looking for answer to fix 2 issues. Thanks for reading and sorry about my English skill.